# Retrieve xml fragment in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I what to retrieve a string representation of the xml fragment for the HB_Base element. Could anyone point it out the best way.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.as.com/ver/ver.IClaimver/Car</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:b22149b6-2e70-46aa-8b01-c2841c70c1c7</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="16b385f3-34bd-45ff-ad13-8652baeaeb8a" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">04eb5b59-cd42-47c6-a946-d840a6cde42b</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://localhost/ver.Web/ver2011.svc</a:To>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Car xmlns="http://www.as.com/ver">
      <carApplication>
        <HB_Base xsi:type="HB" xmlns="urn:core">
          <Header>
            <Advisor>
              <AdvisorLocalAuthorityCode>11</AdvisorLocalAuthorityCode>
              <AdvisorType>1</AdvisorType>
            </Advisor>
          </Header>
          <General>
            <ApplyForHB>yes</ApplyForHB>
            <ApplyForCTB>yes</ApplyForCTB>
            <ApplyForFSL>yes</ApplyForFSL>
            <ConsentSupplied>no</ConsentSupplied>
            <SupportingDocumentsSupplied>no</SupportingDocumentsSupplied>
          </General>
        </HB_Base>
      </carApplication>
    </Car>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Update**

How to use `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode()` that uses `XmlNamespaceManager`. Because it might be better to use xpath like `"/Envelope/Body/Car/carApplication/HB_Base"`

Comment: How are you reading the XML. Really, the answer is more about the particular XML parsing tech you are using, than XML itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace, [using `XLinq` we'd use an `XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387069.aspx) to help make the `XName` which refers to the elements:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile); // or .Parse(@"....")

XNamespace ns = @"urn:core";
// This is where the magic happens: ns + "HB_Base"
var hbBase = xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "HB_Base")
                      .SingleOrDefault();

if (hbBase == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("No such element");

var xml = hbBase.ToString();
```

Using [`XmlDocument` and `XmlNamespaceManager`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316913) instead:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);

var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
nsManager.AddNamespace("s", @"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
nsManager.AddNamespace("c", @"http://www.as.com/ver");
nsManager.AddNamespace("h", @"urn:core");

var hbBase = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(
    @"/s:Envelope/s:Body/c:Car/c:carApplication/h:HB_Base");
if (hbBase == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("No such element");

var xml = hbBase.OuterXml;
```

Comment: How to use XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode() that uses XmlNamespaceManager. Because it might be better to use xpath like "/Envelope/Body/Car/carApplication/HB_Base"

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Very much appreciated. I have a question. From the SOAP xml, do the Car and HB_Base element share the same, default namespace? From you new code, nsManager.AddNamespace("c", @"urn:core"); Does it mean that we define our own name space prefix 'c'?

Comment: @Pingpong: oops, I've corrected my example. Basically, you can give it whatever prefix you'd like as long as the URN's match.

Comment: Thank you very much! From the SOAP xml, do the carApplication element and Car element use the same namespace, given that the carApplication has empty  xmlns value.

Comment: Thanks. If there is only one HB_Base element in the SOAP message, method one seems easier to implement considering few name space being used. Method two requires at least three name spaces.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq; // requires a reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll

// . . .

// Load the XML (in this example, we use a file)
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");

// Initialize the namespace for the target element
XNamespace coreNamespace = "urn:core";

// Choose the first element below the root matching our target element
// (or return null if there is none)
XElement chosenElement = document.Root.Descendants(coreNamespace + "HB_Base").FirstOrDefault();

string xmlString = null;
if (chosenElement != null)
{
    // We found it, now get the string representation of the XML
    xmlString = chosenElement.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XmlNode.OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Load it into xml document and select your node, then retrive the text.  This might not compile.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.loadXml( theString );
doc.SelectSingleNode( "/Envelope/Body/Car/carApplication/HB_Base" ).OuterXml;
```

Comment: He'd need to apply the `urn:core` namespace to that element.